# One word responses that mean 'awesome' / 'excellent'

Tags: words

What other responses are there to positive statements that conveys meanings of 'excellent' and/or 'awesome' in one word. If there aren't any other one word responses, I can accept if they are slightly longer.

Comment: You might want to reconsider your assumptions about the word もちろん。 I does not mean awesome or excellent, not even remotely close. It means "of course; certainly; naturally".

Comment: @stackreader Oh I see, didn't know that. My bad. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

すばらしい - wonderful, fantastic (usually used to describe things that are of good quality, something that's well done, or something that leaves a good impression)

すごい - amazing, sick, cool, crazy (probably the closest to what you are looking for)

すげえ - awesome, sick, crazy, wow (pretty much すごい but a little more casual)

Comment: やばい for a more "teenager" feel

Comment: やばい is super general actually and pretty much everyone uses it. people say it's a bit closer to あぶない but it can also mean awesome, sick, whoa, oh sh*t, wtf, etc